# Можно ли выполнить смещение за один цикл?

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Дан массив размера N. Вставить элемент с нулевым значением
перед минимальным и после максимального элемента массива.

Вот мой код.

```
/* Array103. Дан массив размера N. Вставить элемент с нулевым значением
перед минимальным и после максимального элемента массива. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <limits.h>

const UCHAR Nmax = UCHAR_MAX;

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   UCHAR N = 0, // N - размер массива.
      min_i = 0, //min_i - индекс минимального элемента.
      max_i = 0; // max_i - индекс максимального значения.
   printf_s("Введите размер массива: ");
   scanf_s("%hhu", &N);
   if (1 < N && N <= Nmax)
   {
      ULONGLONG a[Nmax] = {}; // Объявление массива.
      printf_s("Введите элементы массива: ");
      for (UCHAR i = 0; i < N; i++)
         scanf_s("%llu", &a[i]);
      for (UCHAR i = 1; i < N; i++) // Нахождение макс и мин элементов и их индексов.
      {
         if (a[i] < a[min_i])
            min_i = i;
         else
            if (a[i] >= a[max_i])
               max_i = i;
      }
      if (max_i > min_i)
         max_i++; // Увеличиваем max_i, потому что его значение перенесется в следующую ячейку массива.
      N += 2; // Увеличиваем N для добавления 0 элементов.
      for (UCHAR i = N - 1; i > min_i; --i)
         a[i] = a[i - 1]; // Сдвигаем массив для добавления 0 элемента.
      a[min_i] = 0; // Обнуляем min_i, потому что значение минимума теперь в следующей ячейке массива.
      for (UCHAR i = N - 1; i > max_i + 1; --i)
         a[i] = a[i - 1]; // Сдвигаем массив для добавления 0 элемента.
      a[max_i + 1] = 0;
      printf_s("Измененный массив: ");
      for (UCHAR i = 0; i < N; i++)
         printf_s("%llu ", a[i]);
   }
   else
      printf_s("Введено некорректное число.");
   return 0;
}
```

Можно ли выполнить смещения в массиве для того, чтобы вставить нулевые элементы за один цикл?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Надо только знать индексы, куда вставляются нулевые элементы, и чтобы в массиве было достаточно места для вставки...

Comment: Как это можно было бы сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если у вас есть позиции, куда надо вставить 0, и два свободных места в массиве - то почему бы и нет?... Примерно [так](https://ideone.com/Nhgrqt):

```
void addZerosAt(int * a, int N, int p1, int p2)
{
    if (p1 > p2)
    {
        int p = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = p;
    }
    for(int i = N+1; i >= p1; --i)
    {
        if (i > p2) a[i] = a[i-2];
        else a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[p1] = a[p2] = 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[20] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) printf("%2d ",a[i]); puts("");
    addZerosAt(a,15,5,12);
    for(int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) printf("%2d ",a[i]); puts("");
}
```